# How to remove undefined values from array but keep 0 and null

Tags: lodash

In javascript, I want to remove undefined values, but keep the values 0 and null from an array.

```
[ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ]
```

How can I do it cleanly?

Answer (score 121):

You can use  `_.compact(array);`

> Creates an array with all falsey values removed. The values false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN are falsey.

See: https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#compact

Comment: In that case, your answer is not valid as the question states that nulls need to be kept...

Comment: Correct, I pushed an edit to that answer in order to explain it and cite the documentation correctly. The values `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined`, and `NaN` are being removed by `_.compact`.

Comment: your answer is invalid. like it has been stated, the question explicitly disqualifies your answer.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I'm looking for because google redirects me here, even if I ask a different question. Therefore is this answer at this place simple perfect!

Answer (score 48):

The best way using lodash is [_.without](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#without)

Example:

```
const newArray = _.without([1,2,3,undefined,0,null], undefined);
```

Answer (score 15):

No need for libraries with modern browsers. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is built in.

```js
    var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ];
    var updated = arr.filter(function(val){ return val!==undefined; });
    console.log(updated);
```

Comment: This is a good example of when using a framework (that isn't included in the project for other reasons) is superfluous.

Comment: Great answer! I do think there are reasons to stick with Lodash rather than polyfills when looking for consistency across a code base - would you agree with that? **NOTE:** I do realize this was added with `ECMA-262`, and that's a pretty old version of the spec, so in practice this is less of a polyfill potentially more of a "standard implementation."

Comment: More and more developers are moving way from Lodash/underscore. The reason why is browsers now are supporting things natively that they were using the library for. Unless you support IE8, I doubt a polyfill is needed for filter.

Comment: This will still be manually casted to a non-nulllable type and is hard to read + error-prone.

Answer (score 11):

With [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can do simply:

`var filtered = _.reject(array, _.isUndefined);`

If you also want to filter `null` as well as `undefined` at some point:

`var filtered = _.reject(array, _.isNil);`

Answer (score 5):

Using lodash, the following remove only undefined values from the array:

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ];

_.filter(array, function(a){ return !_.isUndefined(a) }
--> [ 1, 2, 3, 0, null ]
```

Or, the following will remove the undefined, 0 and null values:

```
_.filter(array)
--> [1, 2, 3]
```

And if you want to remove null and undefined values from the array, but keep the values equal to 0:

```
_.filter(array, function(a){ return _.isNumber(a) || _.isString(a) }
[ 1, 2, 3, 0 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

With ES6 [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method

```
array.filter(item => item !== undefined)
```

Comment: You can actually use `foo.filter(Boolean)` instead!

Comment: @wle8300 no, you only want to remove undefined values not all the falsy one.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS solution:
By using `===`, you can check if the value is actually `undefined` and not `falsy`.

Both snippets below will give you an array with `[1, 2, 3, 0, null]`.

Both modify the original array.

```js
// one liner - modifies the array in-place
[ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ].forEach( function(val, i, arr){
    if(val===undefined){arr.splice(i,1)}; // remove from the array if actually undefined
});

// broken up for clarity - does the same as the above
var myarray = [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ];
myarray.forEach( function(val, i, arr){
    if(val===undefined){arr.splice(i,1)};// remove from the array if actually undefined 
});
console.log(myarray );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash to do this,
you can use [_.omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy)(object, _.isUndefined); https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy

in the place of _.isUndefined you can even use _.isNumber, _.isNull and lot of functions.
Go to [lodash webside](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) and search "is" in search and you can get the list of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Plain ES6:

`array.filter(a => a !== undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ];
var array2 = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(!(typeof array[i] == 'undefined')){
        array2.push(array[i]);
    }
}
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the given array for elements not equal to undefined.

```
const initialArray = [ 1, 2, 3, undefined, 0, null ];
const finalArray = initialArray.filter(element => element !== undefined);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const finalArray = initialArray.filter(i => Boolean(i))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a value of 0 and behaves the same as .filter(Boolean)